# How to writing and call functions in reactJS component file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a login page, in the input I need a function to change the input type from text to password once the password area onfocus.
When I do something in my html single page, everything is fine, but my supervisor told me to use reactJS component to write it.
So here is what I do in **Password.js**:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Password extends React.Component {
  passInput : function (){
    this.setAttribute("value","");
    this.setAttribute("type", "password");
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Rectangle">
        <img id="pass" className="Group" src="resources/group.png"/>
        <input className="Input" type="text" value="PASSWORD" onfocus={this.passInput}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I also tired:

```
      function passInput(passField){
    passField.setAttribute("value","");
    passField.setAttribute("type", "password");
  }
```

doesn't work also, how should I fix them

Comment: Try using [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Answer (score 2):

In a react way, I would suggest:

- put the `type` and the `value` of the input field in the state of your component.
- use `placeholder` to indicate what the user should type, instead of `value` (see below)
- for the example, I added an `onBlur` event handler, which changes `type` back to `text` (not something you would want to do in real life)

It is generally a very bad idea to change DOM parts that you want react to manage. I would strongly advise not to use refs to change the type of input component.

A more react-like solution to your challenge would be:

```
class Password extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      type: "text"
      placeholder: "text field"
    };
  }
  gotFocus() {
    this.setState({ 
      type: "password",
      placeholder: "password field"
    });
  }
  lostFocus() {
    this.setState({ 
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "text field"
    });
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState ({ 
      value: event.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <input 
          type={this.state.type} 
          placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
          value={this.state.value} 
          onFocus={this.gotFocus.bind(this)}
          onBlur={this.lostFocus.bind(this)}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
    );
  }
}
```

You can find a [working codepen here](https://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/jqddPE?editors=0010).

PS: It looks like your setup is initialising `value` with "password", and as soon as your component gets focus, you change `value` to (empty).
This will break down in a scenario where user types in password, then clicks outside, and then re-focuses. In that scenario, your component will remove (!) any previously typed password.
HTML has the tag `placeholder` which will do a better job. (see codepen for example).

Comment: Thanks so much, by the way, what kind of code style is react way, can u give some principles?

Comment: The best place to find principles is to carefully read the "guides" ([starting here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/why-react.html)) and the "reference" ([starting here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html)) in the official react documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`onfocus` is not part of the React event system. `onFocus` is, however. Try that.

Also you're not setting the input value correctly. It should be `element.value = "";` not `element.setAttribute("value","");`.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#focus-events

```
import React from "react";

export default class Password extends React.Component {
  passInput : function (e){
    e.target.value = "";
    e.target.setAttribute("type", "password");
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Rectangle">
        <img id="pass" className="Group" src="resources/group.png"/>
        <input className="Input" type="text" value="PASSWORD" onFocus={this.passInput}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fkdm8rnL/2/

Comment: thanks but it doesn't make "  e.target.setAttribute("value","");   "work